# Egit installation path error

Tags: eclipse, egit

Eclipse Kepler 4.3.0.v20130530-1801

Egit version: 3.0.0.201306101825-r

After launching Eclipse and checking the Error Log I have the following warning:

> EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git.
>   Hence EGit can't respect system level Git settings which might be
>   configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git
>   installation directory. The most important of these settings is
>   core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true
>   in this system level configuration. The Git installation location can
>   be configured on the Team > Git > Configuration preference page's
>   'System Settings' tab. This warning can be switched off on the Team >
>   Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

So I need an entry in the file gitconfig for core.autocrlf ?

Answer (score 6):

This kind of warning message seems to be related to this [Egit commit](http://git.eclipse.org/c/egit/egit.git/commit/?id=0d264c63788cd6607fe3a83c62f6af5e2d85bc7d).
[This post](https://meteo.unican.es/trac/wiki/EclipseDevelopment/SubversionAndGit) suggests:

> Solution:
>   Go to `Window > Preferences > Team > Git > Configuration > System Settings` Tab
>   Click on `Browse` and find your git system installation.
>   Windows example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig`

Comment: Thanks, but that path C:\Program Files(x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig is for native Git not Egit with Eclipse. I don't have a Git directory in C:\Program Files(x86). I do have a file, gitconfig in C:\Users\mike but since it's not in a folder it can't be chosen using the browse button of the System Settings Tab. If I just choose C:\Users\mike I get the error message: "This directory doen not look like a Git installation directory.
You do not need this setting unless you have a system wide configuration file."

Comment: @mike any chance you can unzip a [portable msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=portable&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size+DownloadCount) somewhere (assuming Windows here) to see if that help?

Comment: I'd really rather not introduce more software that could cause a problem with Egit and Eclipse. Does someone else know how to fix this?

Comment: @mike it won't cause any problem: a portable msysgit is simply a folder that your Eclipse can reference. If that doesn't work, just delete that folder! Easy.

Comment: OK, if I was able to unzip a portable msysgit, what would that tell me? That there's a problem with my Egit installation. Then what steps would I take to correct it?

Comment: @mike that would give you a gitconfig to reference from the setting I mention in the answer. It is worth trying.

Comment: If you're using github, git is located at: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_<abcde...>

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same Warning from Eclipse on an Android SDK installation in Windows 7.  The solution for me was to download Git from [git-scm.download/win](http://git-scm.com/download/win) and installing in the default "Program Files (x86)/Git" directory.  You can then reference this directory by navigating within Eclipse to:

- Window -> Preferences
- Team -> Git -> Configuration
- Tab "System Settings"
- Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\gitconfig

Otherwise, you can ignore the Warning if you have no need for a Git installation.