# EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

How to fix this problem?

Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Egit installation path error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776086/egit-installation-path-error)

Answer (score 4):

As I suggested in "[Egit installation path error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17782192/6309)", it can be linked to the absence of a Git installation (which EGit relies on for the system config path).

Install:

- Git as a [portable msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=portable&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount) if you are on Windows: [`PortableGit-1.8.4-preview20130916.7z`](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/detail?name=PortableGit-1.8.4-preview20130916.7z&can=2&q=portable) (unzip it anywhere you want, and add the `C:\path\to\PortableGit-1.8.4-preview20130916\bin` to the `PATH` environment variable)
- Or Git using the [latest Git Releases](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa) from a [custom PPA (Personal Package Archive)](https://launchpad.net/+help-soyuz/ppa-sources-list.html) if you are on Linux

Answer (score -1):

In my case installation of the latest Git version helped.

Downloaded latest version from https://git-scm.com/download/win and installed it to the same directory as Git was before. Started eclipse and error message from Error log disappeared. I have Cygwin64 installed.