# My Eclipse Luna has an Error about EGIT and I really don't know what to do

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Ok, I'm asking this stupid question because I can't find a useful answer in my problem.

My Eclipse Luna is like a garbage. It doesn't function well, I already tried to delete it and install it again. But the freaking error is still there. Please. I really need a help.

Take note. I don't have a code. I don't have a project yet. I told you guys, I deleted it and install it again so basically, I'm back to zero but the error is still there.

ok. this is my error log.

```
    !SESSION 2014-09-21 21:53:52.206 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-09-21 22:00:59.915
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2014-09-22 17:29:25.194 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-09-22 17:30:20.804
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2014-09-22 19:15:44.856 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-09-22 19:16:23.450
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2014-09-22 22:34:30.202 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-09-22 22:34:49.744
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2014-09-23 21:43:16.747 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-09-23 21:43:40.553
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2014-09-23 23:04:40.502 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-09-23 23:05:01.744
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2014-09-24 00:19:02.983 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-09-24 00:19:59.280
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-24 00:29:37.506
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.eclipse.cdt.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'project/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prjmenu' is invalid): org.eclipse.cdt.ui.manageConfigsAction2

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-24 00:29:37.521
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.eclipse.cdt.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'project/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prjmenu' is invalid): org.eclipse.cdt.ui.buildConfigMenuAction

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-24 00:29:37.522
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.eclipse.cdt.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'project/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prjmenu' is invalid): org.eclipse.cdt.ui.wsselection

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-24 00:35:16.880
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.eclipse.cdt.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'project/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prjmenu' is invalid): org.eclipse.cdt.ui.manageConfigsAction2

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-24 00:35:16.897
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.eclipse.cdt.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'project/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prjmenu' is invalid): org.eclipse.cdt.ui.buildConfigMenuAction

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-09-24 00:35:16.898
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'org.eclipse.cdt.ui' contributed an invalid Menu Extension (Path: 'project/org.eclipse.cdt.ui.prjmenu' is invalid): org.eclipse.cdt.ui.wsselection
!SESSION 2014-09-24 00:40:06.356 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-09-24 00:41:25.914
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
!SESSION 2014-09-24 01:51:20.775 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-09-24 01:52:00.690
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

Comment: is it something because your system architecture and eclipse don't match. Is your eclipse luna and operating system both 64 bit ?

Comment: I'm sure my eclipse and my system are both 64 bit. Last few weeks, my eclipse was normal. I also run a simple prototype of my thesis program. Until the error came, and sh!t happened.

Comment: sorry for my bad english, I'm so groggy.

Comment: Somebody, please help...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its due to the EGIT installation issues.
Please try to set up a new installation of EGIT.

[EGit couldn't detect the installation path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593137/egit-couldnt-detect-the-installation-path-gitprefix-of-native-git)

Plz don't use bad words in the forum.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that, oh well, It's just an overwhelming of stress. I'll try your recommendation, sir.

Comment: the error are still there -_- I follow the instruction in the link you gave me but it's still has an error