# Eclipse - Egit installation path on linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

I necessarily have to make this method. But I use linux(xubuntu).
What should be my EGit path ?

[Egit installation path error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776086/egit-installation-path-error/17782192#17782192)

Comment: sudo apt-get install git. And i restart eclipse. This is work for me. Thank you

Comment: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation" :P sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have git installed
In terminal type

```
git --version
```

If you do not have any output then you do not have git, install it by typeing

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Git should be located in:

```
/usr/lib/git-core
```