# I've downloaded eclipse today and ADT to start an android project and I've encountered an error

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

Nothing is displaying activity_main.xml

[image]

I've spent 3 hours installing everything asked and I have no idea how to fix this error. Has anyone any suggestions?

Expanded message view[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to add android support library (v7) to your project.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998368/the-import-android-support-v7-cannot-be-resolved) might help you.

Comment: Thanks will do it now

Comment: I tried the suggestion in the question prudhvi linked and no luck. Is there another way I can add the v7 library?

Comment: @SSI In the first screenshot you posted, could you expand the 'Message' part so that I could see what's wrong.

Comment: Tip: use Android Studio

Comment: try closing adt or restarting your computer

Comment: Android Studio is way better than Eclipse, which is no longer supported by google.

Answer (score 0):

I could see multiple errors in your screenshot.

1. **Warning:** The environment variable HOME is not set.

   **Refer** ['How to set environment variable'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175089/eclipse-project-wide-error-warning-the-environment-variable-home-is-not-set-t)
2. **Warning:** Egit couldn't detect the installation path 'getPrefix' of native Git.

   **Refer** ['Eclipse Egit error'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17776086/egit-installation-path-error)
3. **Error:** Most of the errors occurred because you don't have Android support library (v7)

   **Refer** ['How to add Android Support v7 libraries in eclipse'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26878803/how-to-add-android-support-v7-libraries-in-eclipse)