# Is it possible to change Eclipse Git location and point it to Source tree embedded Git?

Tags: eclipse, git, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to change default **Eclipse Git** executable location with **SourceTree** installed *embedded* Git executable.

But in eclipse where is the configuration to change git path ?

Reason I am doing this is ,Source Tree has latest Git but separate installed version is not latest *(As I don't have installation right and Through Source Tree I can update Embedded version easily)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse uses **[EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)** which relies on **[JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/)** (a java implementation of Git).

That is why you don't see a `git.exe` path to set. (As opposed to SourceTree, which can use an embedded or a "system" Git)
[You can only specify a Git path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17782192/6309) in order for EGit to respect your Git system config.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has its own GIT. It relay on the EGIT project .

Source tree other other hand can use internal git or System git.
You can take the git version installed by git and try to replace it (replace the EGIT git.exe)

I recommend reading this answer by @VonC as well
[Using native git not jgit in Eclipse git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087558/using-native-git-not-jgit-in-eclipse-git)